# Invalid or unexpected token in javascript object

Tags: javascript

I have an object, part of which look like this:

```
"value": {
    "Some property": [
     {
         "tag": "<script async defer data-domain=\"example.com\" src=\"example.com/somePage.js\"></script>",
         "type": "script"
     }
     ]
 },
```

And right after `"tag":` I got an error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

I have no idea why I'm getting this error. Seems like I can't enter html tags as property value, but how should I define it then?

Comment: @Ivar Yes. Thanks! Sorry for the question then, I think I've chosen wrong keywords for searching the answer.

Comment: No worries. Knowing the issue upfront makes it a lot easier to search for a duplicate on Stack Overflow.